# How to remove specific text from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I want to eliminate first 5 links (complete `<a>...</a>`). Also ALL of the pipes ("|").

```
<p> | <a href="/node/1">link 1</a>  
    | <a href="/node/2">link 2</a>  
    | <a href="/node/3">link 3</a> 
    | <a href="/node/4">link 4</a> 
    | <a href="/node/5">link 5</a> 
    | <a href="/node/6">link 6</a>  </p>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$(".main p a:lt(4)").hide();
```

REVISION 1 ------

getting closer I think with this-

```
$('.main p a').html( $('.main p a').html().replace(/|/gi,'') );
```

REVISED 2 ------

Here is what finally worked for me thanks to your great ideas! the hi:contains helps to ensure that it won't start defacing all my pages.

```
   if($('h1:contains("some specific text")')){
        $(".main p a:lt(4)").hide();
        $('.main p').html($('.main p').html().replace(/\|/g, ''));
    }
```

Comment: When you say you want to eliminate some of the links... what determines which links?

Comment: Do you know exactly which one you want to remove? By href? by index? Did you have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. Also, use remove() if you really don't want them in the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remove all the '|' pipes

```
$("p").html().replace(/\|/g,"");
```

or

```
$("p").html($("p").html().replace(/\|/g,""));
```

If you need to remove a single link,

```
$("p a").eq(1).remove();
```

To remove first 5 links,

```
$("p a:lt(5)").remove();
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Te6ad/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".main p a:lt(4)").hide();

$('.main p').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()) == '|';
}).remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4uKR2/)

Comment: I didn't downvote, because this is the way it has to be done (not using the other answers). But as a suggestion - although it probably works in this scenario and does what the OP wants, you might not want to remove the whole text nodes. I would just use `.each()` to loop through everything returned from `.contents()`, then check if the `.nodeType === 3` like you have it. If it is, then I would just use `this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/\|/g, "");`

Comment: @Ian yes probably, but under the given markup this will serve the purpose

Comment: I know, that's why I said "although it probably works in this scenario and does what the OP wants"

Answer (score 0):

This will replace the bars.

```
$('p').html($('p').html().replace(/\|/g, ''));
```

to replace bars.

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gjWSc/1/

I don't understand what links you wanted removed though..

Comment: i think pipe | has special meaning in regex

Comment: I escaped it though, does it need double escape?
@Abe check my jsfiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't do anything, so I'm not sure why you're including it. Your `.html()` scheme **could** work, but it's far from preferred. Especially if there's more than one `<p>` element. Using `.html()` causes event handlers and element data to be lost, as well as unnecessary characters being replaced. For example, if a "|" is anywhere inside the HTML tags, it would be replaced...but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Why are you providing a fiddle that has the one line of code? It has no HTML, demonstrating nothing.

Comment: @Ian   
I keep sending the wrong one sorry.. jsfiddle.net/gjWSc/1

Comment: @RyanDawkins Like I said, unnecessary characters can be replaced: http://jsfiddle.net/gjWSc/2/ . As well as event handlers and event data being removed

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question,following is the answer to your question:

Html code:

```
<p> 
    | <a id="1" href="/node/1" class="link">link 1</a>  
    | <a id="2" href="/node/2" class="link">link 2</a>  
    | <a id="3" href="/node/3" class="link">link 3</a> 
    | <a id="4" href="/node/4" class="link">link 4</a> 
    | <a id="5" href="/node/5" class="link">link 5</a> 
    | <a id="6" href="/node/6" class="link">link 6</a>  

</p>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var i = 0;
    $('.link').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('p').html($('p').html().replace('|', ''));
        $('#' + id).hide();
        if(i==3)
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    });
</script>
```

Please correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: looks like most efficient solution, but not most compact